# Can I customize Alert Me setup dialog

Tags: javascript, css, alert

I am working on SP2013 on-premise standard edition.

When clicking "Alert Me" button on ribbon, the default SubNew.aspx form will be called. I need to customize the form a bit so that:

1. When setup alert me for particular lists can only setup alert for "new item added"
2. Users can only select "daily summary" for particular lists.

The only way I think of is using Javascript and CSS to hide/disable some fields. But I think it is not easy to control because SubNew.aspx is a global function. Is it suggested method? Any better approach? Thanks.

Comment: Can you state which version of SharePoint you are using and if you are on prem or using SPO.

Comment: Any solution to above question?

Comment: End up I use CSS+JS to hide/disable the undesired fields. The script will be triggered according to URL so that only particular list will be affected.